# How to load a glb file with WebGL without using Threejs

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am new to computer graphics and I have been experimenting lighting and shading with threejs. Now I am looking into WebGL and I would like to write some shaders to improve the image quallity of a glb file. Is there a quick way to load it in the scene without Threejs? Or Should I mix Threejs and WebGL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebGL doesn't support .GLB files. [WebGL just draws triangles, points, and lines](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html). Making a full .GLB viewer requires pretty much reproducing all of three.js. You can do it if you want. You'll need to write shaders that support various kinds of [lights](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-spot.html), [shadows](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-shadows.html), likely [physically based rendering](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58586fa5ebbd1a60e7d76d3e/t/593a3afa46c3c4a376d779f6/1496988449807/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf), [skinning](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-skinning.html), morph targets, [environment maps](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-environment-maps.html), ambient occlusion, normal maps, and more. You'll need to make some kind of [scene graph](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-scene-graph.html) to load it all into since .GLB uses a scene graph to organize the scene. To support shadows you'll need to be able to draw the scene once per light to generate shadow maps. You'll likely need to generate your shaders at runtime to optimize for each object to only use the features it needs. You'll further need to write your own texture loaders, implement some kind of material system, and an animation system. You'll probably want post processing so you can do tone mapping, glow, and depth of field effects.

Or you could just continue to use three.js where it's all been written already. It's open source so if you want to *improve the shaders* then just start editing it.

Comment: Why does this tweet - https://twitter.com/larvalabs/status/1455644959655202819 - say that "GLB (or GLTF) is the standard format for WebGL models"? Doesn't that contradict what you said at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: [Read the spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/). See it has no mention of .GLB or .GLTF. Even the word "model" is only in it in reference to "Document Object Model (DOM)"

Comment: Ah I see. So I assume that tweet was just false information, thank you